# "Android Resource Linking Failure: Style Not Found in .aar Library"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, aar, android-native-library

I'm facing an Android resource linking issue while compiling the parent application after converting an Android native application into a .aar library.

The specific error message I'm encountering is:

> Android resource linking failed: error: resource style/ExoStyledControls.Button.Center not found.
> error: failed linking references.

However, upon checking the referenced resource in the `value.xml` file within the .aar, I can confirm its presence:

```
<style name="ExoStyledControls.Button.Center.Secondary" parent="ExoStyledControls.Button.Center">
    <item name="android:layout_width">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>
```

Despite this, the linking process fails to find this specific style during compilation.

Here are some additional details:

I've ensured that the .aar library is properly generated and integrated into the parent application.
The resource appears to be correctly defined within the library.
Could anyone suggest a potential reason for this resource linking failure and possible troubleshooting steps to resolve it?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!